# Getting straight lines with empty nodes in forest

Tags: forest, linguistics

I have the following trees and I want the lines parallel to the red lines to be straight lines. Right now they are two separate lines but it should be one straight line. Is this possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}

% specification for all trees, "default preamble" appends to existing specification.
% The version with apostrophe replaces it.
\forestset{default preamble'={
    for tree={align=center,parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,anchor=north,base=bottom},
% This would align trees to the baseline. We do not want this for TAG
% where several trees have to be aligned with respect to their center.
%    before drawing tree={
%      sort by=y,
%      for min={tree}{baseline}
%    }
  }}

\forestset{
  declare dimen={child anchor yshift}{0pt},
  adjust childrens child anchors/.style={
    if n children>=2{
      before packing={
        tempdima/.max={max_y}{children},
        for children={
          child anchor yshift=tempdima()-max_y()
        },
      }
    }{}
  },
  default preamble={
    for tree={
      edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)--([yshift=\forestoption{child anchor yshift}].child anchor)},
      adjust childrens child anchors
    }
  },
}


\forestset{
     empty nodes/.style={
     delay={where content={}{shape=coordinate,for siblings={anchor=north}}{}}
     },
sm edges without translation/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,base=bottom},
                 where n children=0{tier=word}{}
                 }
}


    \begin{document}


\begin{forest} 
empty nodes
[{}
  [X \\ {[\textit{u}F]}]
  [{}
    [Y \\ {[F v]}, roof]]]
\end{forest}


\begin{forest}
        sm edges without translation, empty nodes
        [{}
        [X \\ {[\textit{u}F v]}]
        [{}
        [Y \\ {[F v]}, roof]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

*Edit:*
The problem seems to be related to the `roof`.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}



    \begin{document}


\begin{forest} 
nice empty nodes
[{}
  [X \\ {[\textit{u}F]}]
  [{}
    [Y \\ {[F v]}, roof]]]
\end{forest}
\hspace{2cm}
\begin{forest} 
nice empty nodes
[{}
  [X \\ {[\textit{u}F]}]
  [{}
    [Y]
    [Z]]]
\end{forest}



\end{document}
```

Comment: There are quite a few solutions on the site, all of which are compromises.  See [Forest for linguistics - proportional alignment like in qtree](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/361148) or [A nice empty node with nice nodes in forest?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/367868) or [Tree in forest using the style fairly nice empty nodes on](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/324320). Any of these are effectively duplicates of your question. See also [nice empty nodes broken by forest 2.0?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/294245)

Comment: I tried everything and it works but not for my example. The problem is the roof. It seems to break things. If I replace `[Y ...` by `[Y] [Z]` the lines are ok.

Comment: Ok. It would he helpful to show the comparison and make it clear that the issue is the roof.

Comment: I haven't looked at Forest's code for this, but I think it would be easiest not to use `roof` which, I guess (?), may not be designed for this. Are roofs usually expected to line up? @AlanMunn ?

Comment: In one tree, Y has a sibling. In the other, it doesn't. The placement of Y is identical in each case. You don't preserve the angle of the edge when you have an only child, irrespective of whether you use `roof` or not. `roof` is just irrelevant as far as I can see. @AlanMunn

Comment: @cfr Since the roof it supposed to represent *n* unanalyzed children, it should be as wide as whatever you would imagine *n* to be. So if *n* = 2 then it could look like the tree containing Y and Z, which is what Stefan wants.  Probably the simplest solution is to add some `\phantom{X}` to either side of the Y in the `roof` node.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oh, I see. There's no correct way of drawing it, then. For *n*=2, there's no good way of doing it as Stefan wants as far as I can tell, so I think you should answer with that. `fixed edge angles` aligns the `.child anchor` and not `.parent last`, which is what Stefan wants it to do. Since that would not generally be what was wanted, I don't imagine this would be easy to implement at all. And it would be wrong for any other value of *n* anyway. At any rate, any non-fudgy solution can't possibly be worth it, I don't think, so a fudge is the best solution here. IMNSHO.

Comment: ^^ The above is SE's idiotic rendering of my markup. I thought I'd made a mistake, but, no, it is, of course, the site. @AlanMunn

Comment: OK. Thanks! I see. I guess the baseline of the roof is determined by what is under it. So it is `{[F v]}`. What I could play with to get the angle right is the hight of the triangle.

Comment: @StefanMüller The trouble is that you want to treat `.parent last` rather than `.parent` or `.north` as `.child anchor`, even though it isn't. The edge angles are equal. The path to the child anchor is perfectly straight. But that path is not part of the roof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cfr notes in the comments, path that you want to modify with `fixed edge angles` is not part of the `roof`.

The size of the roof is determined by the size of its contents.

So there are two possible solutions I think.

One  is to draw the roof manually with phantom nodes. In this code I've made a macro to wrap features in `[...]` otherwise `forest` gets confused by the brackets in the node drawn under the roof.

The other possibility (which is probably easier) is to put the contents of the roof inside a fixed size box using `\makebox`. I've used `1.5em` as the width just by estimation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\brk}[1]{[#1]}

\begin{forest} 
nice empty nodes
[
  [X \\ {\brk{\textit{u}F}}]
  [
    [\phantom{Y},name=Y]
    [\phantom{Z},name=Z]]]
\draw (Y.north)  -- (Z.north) node [midway,below,align=center] {Y\\{\brk{F v}}};
\end{forest}

\begin{forest} 
nice empty nodes
[
  [X \\ {[\textit{u}F]}]
  [
    [Y \\ {\makebox[1.5em]{[F v]}}, roof]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! I used `~` as a less elegant variant of the `makebox`. Don't tell anybody.